# Update com Laravel não pega o id do model

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, sql-update

Estou tentando realizar uma simples função de alterar a senha do usuário logado utilizando o código:

```
$user = User::find(\Auth::user()->idusuario);
$user->password = bcrypt($request['novasenha']);
$user->save();
```

mas, ele nao funciona.
Percebi que a query executada não pega o id do usuário:

```
update USUARIOS set password = ? where IDUSUARIO is null
```

percebi que este problema de "`where IDUSUARIO is null`" também se repete em outras situações. Como devo proceder a isto? Porque ele não pega o id que esta sendo passado?

---

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = "USUARIOS";
    protected $primaryKey = 'IDUSUARIO';
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'idusuario', 'nomerazao', 'email', 'cpfcnpj', 'telefone', 'idperfil', 'situacao', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getAuthIdentifier() method.
        return $this->attributes['idusuario'];
    }

    public function regras(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\RegrasModel', 'REGRASUSUARIOS', 'IDUSUARIO', 'IDREGRA');
    }

}
```

Comment: Seu update diz para atualizar a senha de todo mundo que tiver ela nula, ou seja mais de uma usuário pode ser afetado.

Comment: Se não estiver enganado o `Auth::user()`ja vai te retornar uma instancia de `User` ai não precisa do `User::find(...)`, poderia ficar `Auth::user()->password = bcrypt($request['novasenha'])`. Posta como esta o seu Model User.

Comment: Já tentei usando assim, e obtive o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é um erro. Na verdade, talvez o nome da coluna na tabela ou qualquer outra coisa esteja errada.

O problema está sendo causado porque `Auth::user()->idusuario` está retornando `NULL`.

Por exemplo, se você tentar fazer um `find`, a consulta ficará assim:

```
 DB::enableQueryLog();
 DB::table('usuarios')->find(null);
 DB::getQueryLog ();
```

Resultado:

> select * from `usuarios` where `id` is null limit 1

Outra coisa: Sempre que você usar um framework procure usar as convenções dele. Seja para banco de dados, ou seja pra qualquer outra coisa (nome de métodos e afins).

O padrão amplamente utilizado no Laravel para `Primary Keys` é simplesmente o `id`.

É possível sim alterar isso, mas lembre-se de fazê-lo de maneira a não fugir muito dos padrões do Framework.

Notei que você utilizou a definição nomes de alguns atributos em UpperCase, e depois tanta acessá-los com LowerCase. Isso não é uma boa ideia!

Mantenha sempre um padrão para escrever seus códigos!

É importante lembrar também que o Laravel vai usar o método `__get` para acessar o valor dos atributos, que por sua vez estão armazenados na propriedade `Model::$attributes`.

Um teste que você pode fazer para detectar o seu erro é debugar os valores que estão sendo armazenados no model, dessa forma:

```
 dd(Auth::user()->getAttributes());
```

Você vai notar que o Laravel não vai fazer a conversão mágica de nomes em UpperCase para LowerCase, para você acessá-los.

No seu caso, nem mesmo é necessário fazer um `find`, já que `Auth::user()` retorna a instância do Model usado para o componente de autenticação.

Veja como você pode fazer:

```
 Auth::user()->update(['password' => bcrypt('senha')])
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, mas os nomes nos atributos não são definidos por mim. Já são do banco que a empresa aqui usa, por isso utilizei "IDUSUARIO" e como o banco é Oracle, ele não é case sensitive no nome dos atributos(pelo menos nunca tive problemas). Em relação ao Auth::user()->idusuario ele retorna 37 que é o id do usuário. Utilizei seu método Auth::user()->update(['password' => bcrypt('senha')]) e ainda assim não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Ao fazer essa função, voce ja carrega a variavel user com o usuario autenticado.

```
$user = \Auth::user();
$user->password = bcrypt($request['novasenha']);
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Faço das palavras de @Wallace Maxters (referênciar um usuário foi removido?) as minhas, mas, me parece que o motivo principal do problema é o valor que você definiu a propriedade "primaryKey" dentro do seu modelo. Está definido com letras maiúsculas, assim:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'IDUSUARIO';
```

O que resulta em uma query com as letras da coluna também em maiúsculo, dessa forma:

```
update USUARIOS set password = ? where IDUSUARIO is null
```

Tente alterar para minúsculo (ou alterar para o valor exato do seu banco de dados), dessa forma:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'idusuario';
```

De qualquer forma, se o seu sistema de autênticação está funcionando, tente usar a facade Auth para pegar o usuário logado, dessa forma:

```
$loggedInUser = \Auth::user();
$loggedInUser->setAttribute('password', '...');
$loggedInUser->save();
```

Um simples teste que você pode estar realizando é, a facade Auth tem um método para pegar o id do usuário autênticado, tente usar o find com este valor, assim:

```
$loggedInUserId = \Auth::id();

$loggedInUser = User::find($loggedInUserId);
$loggedInUser->setAttribute('password', '...');
$loggedInUser->save();
```

Também acredito que não seja necessário adicionar a coluna "idusuario" na propriedade "fillable" do seu modelo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso no `Laravel 7` puxando diretamente

```
use App\User;
User::where('id', '=', Auth::id())
```